# to retrieve data after last space

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am new to oracle.

I have column data as 'ABC DEF AXXXX'.

I want to have 'AXXX' as output.

Could you please help me with this?

How to do this with REGEXP_SUBSTR?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do so. You can simply write following query:-

```
SELECT SUBSTR('ABC DEF AXXXX', INSTR('ABC DEF AXXXX',' ', -1, 1)+1)
FROM DUAL;
```